# Problem with list.files(pattern = paste(...)), file names including dots and numbers

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to read the names of several .RData files using the list.files() function. 
The file names look something like this: "HadCM3.temp236.run.1.Block.801.950.R2.map.RData" or "HadCM3.temp236.run.1.Block.1151.1300.R2.map.RData". Because I want the file name vector to be sorted numerically, I use also the str_sort() function from the stringr package. The code looks something like this:

```
hadcm3.variable <- "temp236"
infile.vect <- str_sort(list.files(pattern = paste("hadcm3.", hadcm3.variable, 
".run.1.block.*.R2.map.RData", sep = ""), ignore.case = TRUE), numeric = TRUE)
```

This section of the code is contained within a much larger script. The funny thing is, when I run the entire script (RStudio version 1.1.456, R version 3.5.1), the mentioned command does not work and the infile.vect variable contains "character(0)". However, when I highlight and run only the mentioned command, it gives the desired outcome, which looks as follows:

```
> infile.vect
[1] "HadCM3.temp236.run.1.Block.801.950.R2.map.RData"
[2] "HadCM3.temp236.run.1.Block.811.960.R2.map.RData"
...
[106] "HadCM3.temp236.run.1.Block.1851.2000.R2.map.RData"
```

Furthermore, I'm pretty confident that the mentioned command is executed also when the whole script is run because the commands just before and after are also executed. The working directory should be correct, too.
I suspect I have a problem with regular expressions here (dots and multiple numbers in the file names), yet have so far been unable to resolve it. How can I make the command work also when run together with the rest of the script?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you run single command and entire script from the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I change the working directory once at the beginning of the script using setwd(...) and don't modify it thereafter. Also, it should be the same when I run the single command.

Comment: be sure to print() your inputs just before running to facilitate debugging. add a `if(!length(list_file_output)) stop()` to be sure the code stops immediately when it encounters your edge case

Comment: Ok, I implemented a  `if(!length(infile.vect)) stop()` statement just after the `str_sort(list.files(...))` command and the execution stops indeed. But what do you mean exactly with the `print()` function? I introduced a `print(infile.vect)` function just before the problematic statement. It prints the expected content of the infile.vect variable (I overwrite the infile.vect variable, could that be the problem?)

Comment: I seem to have found the solution: I was not in an RProject before. When entering the appropriate RProject, my code seems to work. Any ideas why that makes a difference?

Comment: `@PoGibas` `@MichaelChirico` The solution found before seems not to work consistently. It is extremely weird, sometimes the script works well and does everything it should. But most of the time, the list.files command returns an empty vector and the script fails. I now also implemented a proper regex in the list.files(pattern = ...) part but this seems not to help either. Given this weird behaviour (sometimes working and sometimes not) I start to think that there must be something wrong with my computer (virus, ...). Can anyone confirm / disprove this?